# With Chrome FileSystem, let the user choose a Directory, load files inside. And save files in that directory without prompting again

Tags: google-chrome-app

I could not found any examples with this scenario so here we go:

I want the user choose a directory, load all files inside it, change them, and save this file overriding it or saving a new file in that same directory without asking where he want to save.

- I don't know how to list the files of the directory
- I don't know how to save a file in a directory without prompting the filechooser window

I believe it is possible because I see something similar here (last paragraph):
http://www.developer.com/lang/using-the-file-api-outside-the-sandbox-in-chrome-packaged-apps.html

Any answer will be appreciated, Thank you

**EDIT:** Thanks to Chris Johnsen for giving me this great answer:

```
var fileHandler = function() {

  var _entry = null;

  this.open = function(cb) {

    chrome.fileSystem.chooseEntry({
      type: 'openDirectory'
    }, function(dirEntry) {

      if (!dirEntry || !dirEntry.isDirectory) {
        cb && cb(null);
        return;
      }

      _entry = dirEntry;

      listDir(_entry, cb);
    });


  };

  this.save = function(filename, source) {

    chrome.fileSystem.getWritableEntry(_entry, function(entry) {

      entry.getFile(filename, {
        create: true
      }, function(entry) {
        entry.createWriter(function(writer) {

          writer.onwrite = function() {
            writer.onwrite = null;
            writer.truncate(writer.position);
          };

          writer.write(new Blob([source], {
            type: 'text/javascript'
          }));
        });
      });

    });

  };

  this.saveAs = function(filename, source) {

    chrome.fileSystem.chooseEntry({
      type: 'openDirectory'
    }, function(entry) {

      chrome.fileSystem.getWritableEntry(entry, function(entry) {

        entry.getFile(filename, {
          create: true
        }, function(entry) {
          entry.createWriter(function(writer) {

            writer.onwrite = function() {
              writer.onwrite = null;
              writer.truncate(writer.position);
            };

            writer.write(new Blob([source], {
              type: 'text/javascript'
            }));
          });
        });

      });
    });

  };

  var listDir = function(dirent, cb, listing) {
      if (listing === undefined) {
        listing = [];
      }

      var reader = dirent.createReader();

      var read_some = reader.readEntries.bind(reader, function(ents) {

        if (ents.length === 0) {
          return cb && cb(listing);
        }

        var process_some = function(ents, i) {

            for (; i < ents.length; i++) {
              listing.push(ents[i]);

              if (ents[i].isDirectory) {
                return listDir(ents[i], process_some.bind(null, ents, i + 1), listing);
              }
            }

            read_some();
          };

        process_some(ents, 0);

      }, function() {
        console.error('error reading directory');
      });

      read_some();
    };

};
```

Comment: This is a security issue. In general, you can't open a file without first asking the user which one (or ones), and you can't write a file without alerting the user (with a download box). Any browser-specific work-arounds require _the user_ to manually change the configuration of their browser, or start it with specific flags set.

Comment: But I want to ask where the file is to open, I just want to save in the same directory without asking again

Comment: But in the link I've put in the question he can do this to a file (not a folder)

Comment: @MikeW Looks like it is possible!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your `save` method should work fine (mostly, see below) for your second requirement (write to a code-chosen filename without another user prompt), but there are a couple of bugs in `open` (at least as presented in the question):

- Inside the `chooseEntry` callback, `this !== fileHandler` because the callback is invoked with a different `this` (probably the background page’s `window` object).
  You can work around this in several ways:

  - Use `fileHandler` instead of `this` (if you are not using it as any kind of prototype).
  - Use `.bind(this)` to bind each of your callback functions to the same context.
  - Use `var self = this;` at the top of `open` and use `self.entry` (et cetera) in the callbacks.
- You may want to call `cb` for the success case. Maybe you have another way of postponing calls to (e.g.) `fileHandler.save` (clicking on some element to trigger the save?), but adding something like

  ```
  ⋮
  cb && cb(self.entry);
  ⋮
  ```

  after `self.entry = dirEntry` makes it easy to (e.g.) chain `open` and `save`:

  ```
  fileHandler.open(function(ent) {
      fileHandler.save('newfile','This is the text\nto save in the (possibly) new file.');
  });
  ```

---

There is a latent bug in `save`: if you ever overwrite an existing file, then you will want to call `writer.truncate()` (unless you always write more bytes than the file originally held).

```
⋮
writer.onwrite = function() {
    writer.onwrite = null;
    writer.truncate(writer.position);
};
writer.write(…);
⋮
```

---

It looks like you have a good start on the file listing part. If you want to reference the list of files later, then you might want to save them in your object instead of just logging them; this can get a bit hairy if you want to recurse into subdirectories (and also not assume that `readEntries` returns everything for its first call).

```
function list_dir(dirent, cb, listing) {
    if (listing === undefined) listing = [];
    var reader = dirent.createReader();
    var read_some = reader.readEntries.bind(reader, function(ents) {
        if (ents.length === 0)
            return cb && cb(listing);
        process_some(ents, 0);
        function process_some(ents, i) {
            for(; i < ents.length; i++) {
                listing.push(ents[i]);
                if (ents[i].isDirectory)
                    return list_dir(ents[i], process_some.bind(null, ents, i + 1), listing);
            }
            read_some();
        }
    }, function() {
        console.error('error reading directory');
    });
    read_some();
}
```

You could use it in the `open` callback (assuming you add its success callback) like this:

```
fileHandler.open(function(ent) {
    ent && list_dir(ent, function(listing) {
        fileHandler.listing = listing;
        console.log('listing', fileHandler.listing.map(function(ent){return ent.fullPath}).join('\n'));
        fileHandler.save('a_dir/somefile','This is some data.');
    });
});
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your detailed response, I've made some changes to fix the issues you pointed out, (edited my question)  and I want to know if is that right, do I have to save something inside 'open' function?

Comment: Hmm, your code is a bit of a moving target… There are two bugs in [revision 7](http://stackoverflow.com/revisions/21896363/7): passing an array instead of the directory entry to `listDir` (this is the bug you were hitting), and `i` must not be reset in the for loop (this bug would cause an infinite loop). See [here](https://github.com/ChrisJohnsen/StackOverflow-21896363/compare/r7...so21896363%2F7) for the changes to your revision 7 code (and likewise [here](https://github.com/ChrisJohnsen/StackOverflow-21896363/compare/r3...so21896363%2F3) for the changes I intended for your revision 3 code).