# save and change the name of the file with chrome.filesystem

Tags: javascript, html, filesystems, google-chrome-app

Is this possible with chrome.fileSystem to save a file on the client's disk, but by changing the file name. For example, I compress a file and I want that file is stored on the disc with my new name newFile.min.js for example. I can save the file to disk, but not to change its name. And what I would like is that everything is done in a "silent" without a window that asks for the location.

Here is the function I use to save my files:

```
    function saveToEntry(entry, result) {
  setTitle();

  var blob = new Blob([result], {type: 'text/plain'});
  currentEntry.createWriter(function(writer) {
    writer.onwrite = function() {
      writer.onwrite = null;
      writer.write(blob);
    }
    writer.truncate(blob.size);
  });
}

function setTitle() {
  chrome.fileSystem.getDisplayPath(
      currentEntry,
      function(path) {
console.log(path);
        document.title = path;
      });
}
```

Is this possible? And if so, if you have any example to guide me would be great. If not, would be great too :)

Thank you in advance for your advice!

Comment: Are you seeking to save a new file with the changed name, or rename the existing file?

Comment: Hi levi, rename the existing file

Comment: @user1987480 Are you sure? It will destroy the input data.

Answer (score 2):

For that (saving in a separate file), I'm afraid that you need to ask the user for write access for a folder, not an individual file. Then you will be able to create a new file in it.

I suggest that you either ask the user to select a "working" directory, present an in-app file picker from that folder, and save the result next to the normal file.

Alternatively, ask the user to select an "output" folder, and dump the results there.

---

Another solution would be to require a [Native Host module](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/nativeMessaging). You'll be able to access the system with the same rights as the user. It will limit your deployment options though: you'll need a separate installer for your module that can't be hosted on Chrome Web Store.

Comment: Great Xan! But have you any idea how to do it? Because fast like that, I do not see how I can do it ...

Comment: I haven't worked with the API myself, so it'll be a bit hard for me to come up with a sample. Thankfully, [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21896363/with-chrome-filesystem-let-the-user-choose-a-directory-load-files-inside-and) should answer it adequately.