# chrome.filesystem: Rename a file and save it on the client's disk

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-app, google-chrome-os

How could I do with chrome.filesystem to rename a file and save it. For example, if my file is named myfile.txt I would rename the myfile.html and save it without using the saveAs function. And if that's not possible, do I have a solution.

The problem is that I have to save the file on the client's disk. So for me to use the filesystem functions can not be a solution, I have not seen that chrome.filesystem API that allows.

Thank you in advance! I'm a little discouraged. I also watched the browserify aside to work around the problem, but I have not found how to do it.

Comment: Unclear what you're asking; or more precisely, unclear what have you already done and which step presents a problem. State your use case step by step.

Comment: Hello Xan,

here's what I try to do. The user loads a file containing .scss, .coffee, ect. In the list of files, the person clicks on a .coffee file, and compile. What does not work is that once compiled, the .coffee file must be renamed with the .js extension to be usable. This is what I can not do. I do not want the SaveAs option. A bit like CodeKit. The application compiles the file and saves it to disk. This is somewhat the same do I want to implement. But I do not see how to save the file by changing its extension. Am I more clear?

Comment: Well, well, it's a duplicate of your previous question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28460704/save-and-change-the-name-of-the-file-with-chrome-filesystem

Comment: Hi Xan,
Yes it's almost the same thing. But I try to explain it better every time. The advice that people give me are very helpful to me and I try to test them. The last time this in response to one of my two problems. But the file renaming problem remains and I can not find a solution. That's why I wrote this question is a bit duplicate of the previous question. I'm sorry.

Comment: Renaming is not provided by the API at all. It amounts to saving to a new file (and not allowed for the same security reasons). And for improving questions, you should edit existing ones (unless it invalidates already-existing answers)

Comment: ok, I understand. It's a shame nonetheless. There would be no ways to use NodeJS system and its require ('fs') combined with Browserify to operate the client side? For questions, I understand. I'm sorry. I'll keep my questions in my other publications to avoid duplication.

Comment: No, it will not work; browserify cannot work miracles, it's limited to the APIs of the platform it translates to. Do note the update on my answer to the main question.

Comment: Great! Thank you very much for everything.

Answer (score 0):

To rename a file you must have the ability to create a new file on the user's filesystem. You can get this permission by asking the user to open the whole directory in which the project exists. Then you can create any file you want within that directory by calling `getFile` with `{ create: true }` on the resulting `DirectoryEntry`.

**Edit:** See this [example](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/file/filesystem/#toc-file-user-selected) for duplicating files selected by the user. Instead of using `fs.root` as is done here you can use the result of `chrome.fileSystem.chooseEntry` as the `DirectoryEntry` in which the file is saved.

Comment: Hi Reillly, thanks for your answer. 
This way works with HTML5 filesystem. But I can not back up the "physically" file on the disk of the person. Because to do this kind of thing, I absolutely have to go through the API chrome.filesystem right?

Comment: The chrome.fileSystem API gives you regular HTML5 filesystem API objects. Once you have an Entry object it behaves exactly the same.

Comment: But I do not see how I could use the two APIs. Because when I use the filesystem APIs with HTML5, the file path is not the same as if I use the API chrome.filesystem. Chrome.filesystem API with the file path is in the selected folder. While with the other he is I do not know where :). Have you an example. Because if it can work, I would be really happy :) That's the only thing I miss to complete my project. Thank you very much for your help! It is really appreciated.

Comment: The difference you observe is exactly the purpose of the chrome.fileSystem API. It gives you HTML5 filesystem objects referring to files on the user's filesystem in the folder that they specify. If you take a DirectoryEntry from chrome.fileSystem you can create a file in that folder.

Comment: I understand what you said, but I do not know so how. I mean, I am able to write files to disk with chrome.filesystem, but not rename the file with the same API ... Unless you do the equivalent of a saveAs. I will not. You do not have a simple example on hand for me to understand better? I know it's not easy to have this kind of example to hand, but I would really understand :)

Comment: I've added a link to an example of duplicating files using the HTML5 filesystem API with notes on how to adapt it to the Chrome APIs.

Comment: Oh my God! I'll look at it and test. And come back to tell you if everything works. You are my hero :) Thank you so much

Comment: Hi Reilly,
I believe that you sent me as a link might work. I try to make it work, but it does not save anything in the filesystem. Everything is always empty. It is certain that without seeing my code, it is not easy for you. But it is pretty big right now, so I can not really copy / paste here. When I use the filessytem, I see the file in FileList, and when I try to duplicate everything from my code, it shows me a FileEntry. I'm a little mixed up in this. If you have an idea, I'm interested ... Because right now, I do not know what to do with the code. Thank you again for your help ...  :)

Comment: Please post a new question with example code that demonstrates the issue you are having.