# File System to JSON tree asynchronously in Javascript Chrome App

Tags: recursion, google-chrome-app, html5-filesystem

I have been going at this for hours, but my head is going round in circles and confusing itself with async with callbacks...

I am looking to take a DirectoryEntry in a chrome app and recursively create a JSON file tree, like below:

```
[{
  name: ent.name,
  path: ent.fullPath,
  isDir: ent.isDirectory
},
{
  name: ent.name,
  path: ent.fullPath,
  isDir: ent.isDirectory,
  children: [
    {
      name: ent.name,
      path: ent.fullPath,
      isDir: ent.isDirectory
     },
     {
      name: ent.name,
      path: ent.fullPath,
      isDir: ent.isDirectory
     }
  ]
}]
```

In searching I have found many node.js implementations, and have it working in node, but in trying to port it over to FileSystem API and chrome.filesystem in particular, it all goes to pot.

I have also found https://stackoverflow.com/a/21909322 this post which `list_dir` function is very nearly what I want but it creates a flat structure of all files rather than the structure.
I have tried adapting to create the children but cannot get my head around the callbacks.

```
function walkSync(dirent, cb, listing) {
 console.log('Entering walkSync()')
 if (listing === undefined) listing = [];
 var reader = dirent.createReader();
 var read_some = reader.readEntries.bind(reader, function(ents) {
     if (ents.length === 0)
         return cb && cb(listing);
     process_some(ents, 0);
     function process_some(ents, i) {
         for(; i < ents.length; i++) {
           var obj = { name: ents[i].name, isDir: ents[i].isDirectory};

             if (ents[i].isDirectory) {
                 obj.children =  walkSync(ents[i], process_some.bind(null, ents, i + 1), listing);
             }

             listing.push(obj);
         }
         read_some();
     }
 }, function() {
     console.error('error reading directory');
 });
 read_some();
}
```

Any pointers to help me get my head round recursion and callbacks to create this would be a great help and reduce the amount of further lost hours..
Thanks!

Comment: I recommend using [async await](https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/getting-started/primers/async-functions) and a promise library such as [FileSystem.js](https://github.com/kklimuk/filesystem.js) or [bro-fs](https://github.com/vitalets/bro-fs) to avoid having to cope with callbacks.

Comment: I may be wrong, but I have looked at those and similar libraries, but they look to work with HTML5 FS API which creates a sandboxed area to start creating files and dirs, whereas chrome.filesystem can access existing directories and contents on the system... or am I wrong? sorry new to the FS API.
I am looking for a user to select an existing directory and then create the tree

Comment: UPDATE: Ah, I think I have cracked it, and using bro-fs, but ignoring the .init() functions and just passing in the DirectoryEntry I retrieve from chrome.filesystem, seems to work now, thank you

Comment: Here is an example on creating a directory structure: https://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/file/filesystem/#toc-dir